# What view/template to use to play a video on Android Automotive?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, android-automotive

I'm playing around with Android Automotive (NOT Android for Cars!) and I'm looking for an alternative to VideoView, which isn't available to Automotive.
What I want is to play a simple MP4-file, which gets rendered including some nice and neat play and seek buttons. I wonder, how to do this in Automotive, because there is no Template or something similar available, which can be used in a similar fashion as VideoView, which is commonly used for regular Android applications.

Any suggestions?